# Record sound from only specified game (program)

Tags: windows-10, audio, recording, audio-recording

I'd like to record video and audio from a game but not my sound when I talk on TeamSpeak, Skype, etc. How can I record only the sound of the game?

I found out that it is possible via Virtual Cable, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed you need some form of virtual audio device (on Windows). Examples of this are [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) and [Voicemeeter/Their VAC](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm).

In order to record the sound it's easiest to setup the virtual audio cable as the default output device and tell Windows you want to listen to this device on your normal sound card. For programs you don't want to record you'd need to have the option available to select the output device. For TeamSpeak this can be done in the options. Other software, especially games, don't necessarily support this.

On option here is to have multiple virtual devices and switch after you start the software you want to output on a certain virtual audio device. But certain programs like browsers tend to be able to dynamically switch to new default output devices while not giving you the option to set the output device. This also applies to certain games so watching some VOD and playing games can be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I still don't know how to do it..can't u help me in private? :D